# invoking an event on click of button on another component

Tags: angular

I have a paginator (from primeNG) where I have implemented some logic on the `onPageChange` event like so:

```
<p-paginator
    #p
    class="paginator_mot"
    [alwaysShow]="false"
    [rows]="configuredValuePerPage"
    [totalRecords]="totalmotrec"
    pageLinkSize="3"
    (onPageChange)="paginateMotList($event, motDetails)"
  >
  </p-paginator>
```

Now this paginator is present in `compA`. I want that when I click on a button present in `CompB`, this `onPageChange` event should fire. Is this possible? Please attach some working link for better understanding.

Comment: `CompB` will fire an event and `CompA` will listen to that. When `CompA` listens the event just run the `paginateMotlist` function. If you have parent child components the use event emitters. Otherwise data sharing service. Comment below if you need code example

Comment: code example needed

Comment: Just tell me is there any relation between components? Like parent child?

Comment: The two components are siblings. They are present inside one parent component

Answer (score 0):

this is a use case for the shared service model of component communication, which is a common angular pattern.

step 1 make a service with an observable to send events:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) // provide appropriately, this will be a singleton
export class PaginationService {
  private pageSource = new Subject(); // keep subjects private
  page$ = this.pageSource.asObservable(); // public observable 
  page(event, motDetails) { // method to trigger subject, change params as needed
    this.pageSource.next({event, motDetails});
  }
}
```

step 2 inject service into components, subscribe in interested component and trigger in triggering component:

```
@Component({...})
export class ComponentA implements OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  constructor(private paginationService: PaginationService) {
    // subscribe to event, store subscription
    this.sub = this.paginationService.page$.subscribe(({event, motDetails}) => {
      // trigger onPageChange event here, not sure if this is correct from your given code.
      this.paginateMotList(event, motDetails);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe(); // unsubscribe from events to avoid memory leaks
  }
}

@Component({...})
export class ComponentB {
  constructor(private paginationService: PaginationService) { }

  page(event, motDetails) { // call this method to trigger the event with needed params
    this.paginationService.page(event, motDetails); 
  }
}
```

Comment: when i call  ``this.paginationService.page(event, motDetails);`` in componentB, ``event, motDetails`` are not recognized

Comment: can you add an example?